# [NSObject description]

Tags: objective-c, ios, c, foundation

Hello can you give me an example of the usage of this method

```
+(NSString *)description
```

Do I use description with an instance of a NSObject (any kind of object) or NSString?

or do I use without an instance, directly using NSObject (any kind of object) or NSString?

Comment: Note that you should never use the `description` method for any purpose outside of debugging or logging.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The description of the instance gives you information about the specific instance you have created.

**- (NSString *)description;**

```
NSString *string = [NSString alloc] initwithString:@"aString"]];
[string description];
```

*Gives you information about this instance (location in memory etc)*

On the other side:

**+ (NSString *)description;**

```
[NSString description];
```

*Gives you information about the class NSString.*

The same rules apply to all NSObject subclasses and other classes that conform to NSObject protocol such **NSArray**, **NSDictionary** **NSProxy**  etc

Comment: Actually, `-description` is a required method for any class that implements the `NSObject` *protocol*. That includes NSObject subclasses, but also classes that aren't NSObject subclasses but which impelement the protocol such as NSProxy.

Comment: Thanks for your great answer. Just like I thought.

Comment: @GeorgeSach Wow awesome! It's a shame i can up-vote only once!

Comment: My question is how can `NSObject` call `[NSObject description];` Since `NSString` is a subclass of `NSObject`, how does an `NSObject` return a string? I get how class forwarding would cover the protocol, but how can that work for the description class method?

Answer (score 4):

Let's say we have:

```
@interface randomObject : NSObject
{
    NSString  *yourString;
}
```

and somewhere:

```
yourString = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"random text"];
```

then we can override `randomObject` like this...

```
- (NSString *)description
{
  return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", yourString];
}
```

after we done this we can call a NSLog with our NSObject:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
    randomObject *ourObj;

    ourObj = [[randomObject alloc] init];

    NSLog(@"%@", ourObj); //  this will output "random text"
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You seem to mainly be confused about the difference between class and instance methods.

`NSObject` declares the *class method* [`+[NSObject description]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000050-description), which, as the docs tell you "Returns a string that represents the contents of the receiving class.". If you send the message `description` to a class object, like so:

```
[NSArray description];
[NSNumber description];
[[someObject class] description];
```

this method will be called and you'll get the string the class uses to describe itself.

On the other hand, the [`NSObject` *protocol*](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/NSObject) declares a required *instance method* [`-[id<NSObject> description]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000052-BBCBAFEH), which will return "a string that describes the contents of the receiver". When you send this to an instance, you get a string representing it:

```
NSNumber * n = [NSNumber numberWithInt:10];
[n description];
NSArray * arr = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Lemon", @"curry", @"?", nil];
[arr description];
NSDicitonary * d = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:arr forKey:n];
[d description];
```

All subclasses of `NSObject` inherit both of these methods, and they can be overridden just like any other. Notice, for example, that `NSDictionary` and `NSArray` format themselves and send `description` to the objects they contain.

It should also be noted that, when using `NSLog()`, the `%@` format specifier causes `description` to be sent to its argument (whether it's a class object or an instance).

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer.
When I use the class method
[NSArray description];
it gives me expected expression error.

Comment: Do you have that inside of a method or function?

Comment: Hello, I would really appreciate it if you gave me an example of the correct usage of [NSArray description];.

Comment: The code I gave above is correct; it needs to be in the body of a method or function. If you're having a particular problem with some code you've written, you should feel free to post that as a question.

Answer (score 2):

The call most normally used it actually

```
- (NSString *)description;
```

It is used on normally instances, not classes.  It can be overridden in custom classes to provide detailed information about an object.  If you attempt to access a class as as string, the description method will automatically be called.

```
NSLog(@"array: %@", array);               //Identical
NSLog(@"array: %@", [array description]); //Identical
```

You can use it on classes just as you stated

```
[NSArray description];
```

Comment: There's also a class method version: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000050-description

Comment: What do you mean by "attempt to access a class as a string"?

Comment: Objective-C has dynamic typing meaning, at runtime, you can access a variable of any class as a member of another class.  This is a powerful, and often harmful, aspect of the language.

Comment: The `%@` format specifier doesn't "access a class as a string" -- it sends `description` to the argument.

Comment: @JamesPaolantonio I'm not sure I follow you. At any rate, the "%@" format specifier can accept any Objective-C object, not just strings. When you pass `array` as a parameter to NSLog with a format string that includes "%@", `description` will indeed be called, but not because you're somehow trying to "access" `array` "as a string".

Answer (score 1):

```
+(NSString *)description
```

Is used mainly for debug and is used by instances. It allows to print a description of the object.